# How to change the color of a cell of AjaxEditableLabelColumn in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a `AjaxEditableLabelColumn` with `onChange` method. I need change the backgroundcolor of the cell I just edited.
This is the code:

```java
private AjaxEditableLabelColumn<User, String> createMyEditableColumn(String propertyExpression, boolean sortable) {
    AjaxEditableLabelColumn<User, String> column = new AjaxEditableLabelColumn<User, String>(propertyExpression, sortable) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onChange(AjaxRequestTarget target, IModel<User> model) {

            User newRecord = model.getObject();

            if (newRecord.hasChanged()) {
                if (newRecord.isRight()) {
                    ((((TURN GREEN))))
                } else {
                    ((((TURN RED)))))
                }

            } else {
                ((((REMOVE COLOR))))
            }
        }

    };
    return column;
}
```

Comment: I dont see this is a Wicket Class: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/ What  is it?

Comment: I guess @Mot4 made own class, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you rather add the attribute modifier behavior just one and change the model of css class or style attribute.

**CODE:**

```
    private AjaxEditableLabelColumn<User, String> createMyEditableColumn(String propertyExpression, boolean sortable) {

        final IModel<String> cssModel = Model.of("bkg-default");
        AjaxEditableLabelColumn<User, String> column = new AjaxEditableLabelColumn<User, String>(propertyExpression, sortable) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

           @Override
           protected void onChange(AjaxRequestTarget target, IModel<User> model) {

                User newRecord = model.getObject();

                if (newRecord.hasChanged()) {
                    if (newRecord.isRight()) {
                        cssModel.setObject("bkg-green");
                    } else {
                        cssModel.setObject("bkg-red");
                    }
                } else {
                    cssModel.setObject("bkg-default");
                }
           }
           // The following line is unnccessary if you already add 
           // component for to be render in AjaxEditableLabelColumn
           target.add(this);

       };
       column.add(new AttributeModifier("css", cssModel));
       return column;
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
.bkg-default { background-color: transparent; }
.bkg-green { background-color: green; }
.bkg-red { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add a AttributeModifier to the cell and refresh it. AjaxEditableLabelColumn looks like a custom implementation, so I'm guessing a little bit:

```
        @Override
        protected void onChange(AjaxRequestTarget target, IModel<User> model) {

            User newRecord = model.getObject();

            if (newRecord.hasChanged()) {
                if (newRecord.isRight()) {
                    item.add(new AttributeModifier("style", "background-color:green;"));
                } else {
                    item.add(new AttributeModifier("style", "background-color:red;"));
                }

            } else {
                    item.add(new AttributeModifier("style", ""));
            }
        target.add(item); //refreshing
        }
```

Obviously you can make this more robust by using Models and/or overwriting the newValue method of AttributeModifier.

Comment: I do not recommend add the same behavior manytimes. In this case it adds the behavior eachtime you click or trigger AJAX change event. That means you create too many instances that just replace the same key in the tag attribute map until the last one is reached. For that case using the model is a better solution.